# Livereload with Compass 0.13 and Drupal omega 4 subtheme

Tags: drupal-7, compass-sass, livereload

Upgrading to Compass 0.13 with `$rhythm-unit: 'rem';` immediately regains control over consistent sizes of block headings etc. of Omega sub-themes. Great!

BUT ... `livereload` no longer works.
The scss directories are correctly watched and compilations to css carried out upon saving of scss source. But browsers don't get connected.

`drush omega-guard` informs: `LiveReload 1.6 is waiting for a browser to connect.` and, after automatic re-compilation: `Reloading browser: css/m2-omega.styles.css` however, the browser is not refreshed.

Is there an unmet dependency on livereload?

Comment: I am not sure if this can help you, but if it helps you kindly revert back to post answer for idiots :)

https://drupal.org/node/1909044